# Mother Russia Bleeds "happy ending"?

Tags: achievements, mother-russia-bleeds

I just completed Mother Russia Bleeds. For that, I received the "sad ending" reward. I noticed that there is also a "happy ending" achievement, so there must be an alternative ending. Does anyone know how to achieve this alternative ending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to beat the final boss without using drugs. [Source](http://showgamer.com/endings-mother-russia-bleeds/)

> You can to solve it in a fight against the final boss of the game. You will get a good ending if you destroy him without drugs. It is important to understand that you do not need any treatment, don’t use - keys F and R.
>   If you use medication or rage at least once, you will get absolutely bad ending.